# Ratio test proof, generalisation part[solved]

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

In the first part of the proof of the ratio test, we want to prove that the if the $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = L < 1$ then the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

I understand the parts: $$\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}   - L\right | < \epsilon \iff L-\epsilon < \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < L + \epsilon \iff a_{n+1}<(L+\epsilon)a_n$$
but then we generalise that last part to: $$a_{n+k}<(L+\epsilon)^k a_n$$
which is quite unclear to me. I understand the rest of the proof, it's just this part that I don't know how we got.

**edit:** Solved, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prove this by induction. We know:

$$
a_{n+1} < (L + \epsilon)a_n
$$

Suppose:

$$
a_{n+p} < (L + \epsilon)^pa_n
$$

Then

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{n+p+1} &<& (L + \epsilon)a_{n+p}
\\        &<& (L + \epsilon)((L + \epsilon)^pa_n) = (L + \epsilon)^{p+1}a_n
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Hence

$$
a_{n+k} < (L + \epsilon)^ka_n \forall k
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that using induction

or also you can see it directly, if you write it down for $a_{n+2}$:

$a_{n+2} < (L+\epsilon)a_{n+1}< (L+\epsilon) (L+\epsilon) a_{n} =(L+\epsilon)^2 a_{n}$

That shows how it works.